# how to integrate a Plug-in Project template into an existing eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, help-system

I have already developped a Java project using Eclipse.
Now I would like to integrate an help system to allow the user to open a guide.

Browsing other questions i found [this tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-AddingHelpToRCP/index.html) to set up Eclipse environment in order to use the Eclipse Help System. Anyway, this tutorial and all documentation I found since now, only explain how to use this system creating a new plugin project.

But what about if I want simply add the help system to an existing Java Project created in Eclipse IDE?
Which step should I follow to update my project configuration?
Is it possible to integrate Eclipse Help system, without using eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the help system you point to is an eclipse plugin based system, useful with RCP programs.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP  It will only run in the context of an RCP application.

You *might* be able to write an RCP app that contains only help, launch it, and communicate with it through http from your java app, but it's not a simple integration ... and you still have to build your help documents so that org.eclipse.ui.help can see them.